# Symfony doctrine Undefined index in native query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to perform a native query on my FacebookEventResult entity, and create a join with my FacebookEvent entity.

The relevant mappings in FacebookEventResult:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FacebookEvent", inversedBy="facebookEventResults")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="facebook_event_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 **/
protected $event;
```

The relevant mappings in FacebookEvent:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FacebookEventResult", mappedBy="event")
 **/
protected $facebookEventResults;
```

My query code:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('AppBundle:FacebookEventResult', 'fer');
$rsm->addFieldResult('fer', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('fer', 'event_date', 'eventDate');
// $rsm->addFieldResult('fer', 'facebook_event_id', 'event'); // this doesnt help
// some other mappings here as well, also tried without

$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('AppBundle:FacebookEvent' , 'fe', 'fer', 'event');
$rsm->addFieldResult('fe', 'id', 'id');
// some other mappings here as well, also tried without

$sql = 'SELECT *
        FROM facebook_event_result fer
        INNER JOIN facebook_event fe ON fer.facebook_event_id = fe.id';

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
return $query->getResult();
```

When executed I get the following error:

**Notice: Undefined index: id**

I have tried to follow [these instructions](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#examples) from Doctrine.

Comment: i think you need to specify all the column field you want to retreive in the select statement

Comment: Please can you let me know what exactly error. put your error here

Comment: He thnx for answering. I resolved it some other way, and I don't have this code anymore to test it again

Answer (score 0):

See: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/2482

I didn't see any resolution to this in the github thread, *but* they did suggest an alternative which did work for me: `ResultSetMapping#addScalarResult($columnName, $alias)`

So, something like this should work:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'id');
$rsm->addScalarResult('event_date', 'eventDate');

$sql = 'SELECT *
    FROM facebook_event_result fer
    INNER JOIN facebook_event fe ON fer.facebook_event_id = fe.id';

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
return $query->getResult();
```

---

**NOTE:** This came as a temporary fix to me; it appears their own examples don't work or require something that is missing and is not well documented.

Answer (score -4):

If you forgot please add this one in your script

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
```

Comment: wat? How does this answer the question?

Comment: This has absolutely _nothing_ to do with the problem. If you have a real suggestion on how to resolve this then please modify your answer and I will be happy to change my vote.